# jQueryUI Draggable , trigger the "stop" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

The object that i must drag can also be moved by the event of the keyboard (key up , down , left and top)

In the drag event of any object i have a function that do something , and when the object is moved by the keyboard i must call the drag stop event

All of this solutions doesn't work

[Jquery .trigger('stop') method for .draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590698/jquery-triggerstop-method-for-draggable)

```
$("#obj").draggable().trigger("dragstop");

$("#obj").trigger("dragstop");
```

[How would you use Trigger to fire the jquery draggable start, drag, stop events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153595/how-would-you-use-trigger-to-fire-the-jquery-draggable-start-drag-stop-events)

```
var s = [{ClientX:0, ClientY:0, target:""},{}];
$("#obj").draggable("option" , "stop").apply($("#obj") , s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're binding the `stop` (*or any other*) event while initializing as follows:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
 stop: function(ev,ui){
 }
});
```

In that case, `trigger` won't work.

Bind the event separately,

for example:

```
$("#draggable").on("dragstop",function(ev,ui){

});
```

Then trigger will work.

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#draggable").on("dragstop", function(ev, ui) {
  alert("draggable stop");
});
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#draggable").trigger("dragstop");
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable"></div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: now the event is call , but the parameter ui ( $(obj).on("dragstop", function(ev, *ui*){..}) is undefined when i trigger the dragstop event

Comment: the problem is present also in your example

Comment: @WhiteLine obviously it'll be empty. It is not triggered by an actual drag, What else do you expect...